# How do I remember a logged user using AngularFire and Firebase Simple Login?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

This is what I'm using for Authentication:

```
   new FirebaseSimpleLogin(new Firebase("firebaseURL"), function(error, user) {
      if (error) {

      } else if (user) {
        // angular ngCookies service
        $cookies.user = args.user.email;
      } else {

      }
    });
```

To store all the todos per user, I'm simply storing his email ID against each todo. The problem with this approach is that I can modify the cookie replacing with someone else's email then I could see their todos.

Is there a way to know who has logged in using Firebase simple login instead of looking at the cookie? Is there any better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `angularFireAuth`, which will bind a model to user authentication state:

```js
function MyController($scope, angularFireAuth) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/");
  angularFireAuth.initialize(ref, {scope: $scope, name: "user"});
}
```

$scope.user will then be null if the user is logged out, and set to a user object when the user is logged in. Learn more at http://angularfire.com/documentation.html#authentication